# Wp ecommerce current menu item of next page doesn't show

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I made a custom menu item on my website named Toys and linked it with 'custom links' to: http://mydomain.com/toys/our-toys/

When I go to the website the menu item Toys gets a current menu item with a green background color (as it is supposed to be). On this page you can navigate to another page, because I limited the products with 6 items every page. When I click on the next or last page button, I go to: http://mydomain.com/toys/our-toys/page/2/. On this page, the current menu item has disappeared.

Does anyone know how to set the current page items when I go to the next and previous pages? I use wp ecommerce with mazine theme.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress automatically adds a `.current-menu-item` class to the `li` of your current menu item, check that that is the class that is being styled and not a custom class or pseudo element.

e.g.

```
.nav .current-menu-item a {
  color:red;
}
```